# Regex pattern matching with pg_trgm (trigram matching)

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, pg-trgm

I have a database in postgresql called mydata with a field called text. I'm interested in doing regex pattern matching and only returning the snippet of the match, not the entire text. I know you can use pg_trgm (creates a trigram matching index) to speed up the search, but is there a way to do both the searching and matching as a combined statement?

I'll provide some context:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX text_trgm_idx ON mydata USING GIN(text gin_trgm_ops);
```

I'll use the example regex pattern of '(1998.{0,10})', but I'm actually interested in any type of pattern, not just this example string.

Desired pattern match, but doesn't appear to use pg_trgm indexing (note title is another field, but not the one I'm matching on):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT title, regexp_matches(text, '(1998.{0,10})') FROM mydata;
 Seq Scan on mydata  (cost=0.00..2257.89 rows=201720 width=73)
 Planning time: 0.047 ms
 Execution time: 2493.105 ms
```

Now, adding the WHERE field.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT title, regexp_matches(text, '(1998.{0,10})') FROM mydata WHERE text ~ '(1998.{0,10})';
 Bitmap Heap Scan on mydata  (cost=28.01..35.88 rows=20 width=73) 
Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 20
   Heap Blocks: exact=723
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on text_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..28.01 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.930..0.930 rows=2059 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (text ~ '(1998.{0,10})'::text)
 Planning time: 15.889 ms
 Execution time: 1583.970 ms
```

However, if we removed the pattern match, we'd get even better performance, so I suspect we're doing the same work twice:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT title FROM mydata WHERE text ~ '(1998.{0,10})';
 Bitmap Heap Scan on mydata  (cost=28.01..35.78 rows=2 width=41)
 Recheck Cond: (text ~ '(1998.{0,10})'::text)
   Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 20
   Heap Blocks: exact=723
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on text_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..28.01 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=1.136..1.136 rows=2059 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (text ~ '(1998.{0,10})'::text)
 Planning time: 1.980 ms
 Execution time: 554.589 ms
```

Furthermore, if there are any suggestions on how to get the best performance when doing a regex pattern match in postgres, I would appreciate further material. I'm not constrained to any version of postgres.

Comment: Sidenote: If you don't use the global flag (`g`) of `regexp_matches`& want to capture the whole match only, you could use `SUBSTRING(text FROM '1998.{0,10}')` instead (it's just easier to deal with, but won't help on the performance of your query).

Comment: `pg_trgm` indexes only speed up queries with the patter matching **operator(s)**: `~` (and `~*`). It cannot speed up any other patter matching function. Note: `regexp_matches` and `~` do slightly different things, i.e. `~` goes for a match only (`returns boolean`) which is easier to determine than **extracting** a match (which is done by `regexp_matches`). I'm afraid this extracting cannot be enhanced in any way...

Comment: ... But, if you can simplify your original pattern to a "covering" `LIKE` pattern (i.e. in your actual example, it will be `text LIKE '%1998%'`) then your query could run actually faster: http://rextester.com/NNX37309

Comment: Using regexp_matches followed by LIKE is a good trick.