# Does the length of a field matter for regex lookups? Will an index help speed up regex queries?

Tags: postgresql

I'm adding an "ancestry" path field to my model. Which is the primary ID of all the previous rows in the ancestry. My primary ID is a UUID. So an ancestry path might look like this for a first child `"915ce8be-4dc7-4202-a564-089596821d27."`, and this for a second child `"d400e972-3aa9-4709-b55b-a1d1a88201d1.118ca89c-b6f1-4164-914d-d47d4c962605."`. My questions are:

1. Would it be fast to add an additional auto incremented integer ID to the model, so that the ancestry paths look like `"123.423.534.578"`, instead of the UUID version? Or would the difference be negligent? The type of queries I'd be doing is regex against the `ancestry_path`.
2. Would an index do anything to speed up these regex queries? If you want to find all rows where the ancestry starts with `123.345` then I could see how an index might help, but I'm not sure if indexes are used in regex lookups. Are they?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a "hierarchy", there are better ways to do that.

One option is to use an array that defines the path:

```
create table data 
(
  ancestry uuid[]
);
```

This will also have the added benefit that it's much more efficient to store than using concatenated strings.

Additionally you can create a GIN index on the array column which will [support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) e.g. the `@>` operator.

```sql
select *
from data
where ancestry @> array['d400e972-3aa9-4709-b55b-a1d1a88201d1', '118ca89c-b6f1-4164-914d-d47d4c962605']
  and ancestry[1:2] = array['d400e972-3aa9-4709-b55b-a1d1a88201d1', '118ca89c-b6f1-4164-914d-d47d4c962605']
```

The `and ancestry[1:2] = ...` part is necessary because the "contains" operator also includes rows where the two values occur somewhere else in the array. But it is useful to reduce the number of potential rows using the index (**if** feasible).

---

If your primary keys weren't UUIDs, you could use the [ltree module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html) which offers efficient access to such a structure. However, it does not allow a `-` as part of the values. So your options to use `ltree` are to either replace the `-` with `_` or use integers as the primary key.

Then you could use that and either a [B-tree or GiST index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html#id-1.11.7.30.6) depending on the [operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html#id-1.11.7.30.5) you need for your queries.

Comment: This is really interesting, I had never heard of the GIN index. So let me see if I can understand this correctly, because I don't see a lot of dummied down for a newbie like me GIN docs. But it sounds like instead of storing `UUID.UUID.UUID` as a concatted str. I store a JSONB array with `[UUID1, UUID2, UUID3]`, then I could see all children of say `UUID2`, by querying `ancestry @> array[UUID1, UUID2] and ancestry[1:2] = [UUID1, UUID2]`? I assume if my query array is 3 long it'd be `ancestry[1:3]`? Why is it `[1:2]` instead of `[0:1]`? Are jsonb values 1 indexed?

Comment: You are right about the `[1:3]` - as I explained it's there to remove the false positives from the "overlaps" operation. "*Why is it [1:2] instead of [0:1]"* because array indexes start at 1 in Postgres. I don't understand the reference to JSONB, this is all about native arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really certain that I understand what you're doing but I can say two things:

a) Have you considered the model where each row points to its parent only instead of having the whole tree encoded on a single column separated by dots, if I understood your idea correctly? Depending on the particulars it can be more or less efficient - especially on how many levels up the hierarchy you'll search for in the typical case - if there are few levels in the typical case just pointing to the parent on each row can be really efficient and avoids having to use regex.

b) Depends on how are you actually doing these matches, are you using `LIKE` or `regex_match` or `~`? See [Regex pattern matching with pg_trgm (trigram matching)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229592/regex-pattern-matching-with-pg-trgm-trigram-matching) for details (on the question and comments) over the trigram index that PostgreSQL supports.

EDIT: After the clarifications you've added as a comment, my answers would be

1. For sure using integer ids would accelerate regex execution in the general case, as the strings would be shorter both the needle and (most importantly) the haystack
2. pg_trgm indexes support `~` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.41.7)

So, my suggestion would be to use ints for the combined column, pg_trgm as an index and also to measure: try several approaches (for example trying the query with both LIKE and ~) with a big table of fake data, seeing what will PostgreSQL do via EXPLAIN and then choosing the best option for your use case.

Comment: A) I am also using the `parent_id` pattern for quick child lookups. But I also want the path so I can find ALL children on the tree above a below a certain comment if needed.
B) I am using `~` right now.